# Lost changes after accidently calling git stash

Tags: git

I had local uncommited changes to master. And I accidently called 'git stash' command. I lost my changes, i.e the master was reverted to last state from origin master. Is there way to return my lost uncommited changes ?

Comment: Using `git stash apply stash@{0}` should put the changes back - My other advice is to commit early and often.

Comment: It returned the changes. Thank you so much !

Comment: Yes. But how to accept answer since it is in the comment

Comment: There's nothing to accept here, I'd expect this question to get closed soon. I'd either accept the duplicate or delete the question altogether.